# Add tab after <html> tag editor style in Intellij format

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

We use Nx, editorconfig, eslint, and prettier and I use IntelliJ. I'm running into an issue that's driving me a bit crazy which is that I want auto-formatting on save but for HTML files specifically IntelliJ is formatting it in a way that causes the format/linting checks to fail. The difference is this:

Acceptable to our formatting rules:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

IntelliJ however is doing this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

I found setting about not indenting some tags but I do want to indent the lines. To make it more confusing, the IJ preview looks correct.

I'm not sure what else to check or do.

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

Just want to note that I'm fairly certain it's not a third party thing as I can prevent this from happening if I disabled the "Reformat code" checkbox for HTML under the save options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found it, but strangely I see 0 docs on this anywhere. I went through the project settings and in my .idea folder under `codeStyles/Project.xml` I found this line:

```
<option name="HTML_UNIFORM_INDENT" value="true" />
```

Googling this shows one GitHub gist but no documentation anywhere. Bing's AI explained what it was but had 0 sources on that info.

I set it to false:

```
<option name="HTML_UNIFORM_INDENT" value="false" />
```

And now it works. If I de-indent `<head>` for example, on save, it will now indent it as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue, that was fixed by clearing the field `Do not indent children of` containing a list of elements where IntelliJ would not indent. Afterwards, the code was indented as intended. The option is under `Editor > Code Style > HTML`

[image]